# Are all matrices of the following form Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix $A$ (and it is square and nonsingular), is $A^* A $ Hermitian? Also, does $A $ have to be nonsingular for this to hold?

Comment: Seriously, just write it down. It's less that a one-liner.

Comment: Do you know that $\;(AB)^*=B^*A^*\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For any matrices $A, B$ with compatible dimensions,
$$(AB)^\ast = B^\ast A^\ast$$
A matrix $M$ is hermitian iff
$$M^\ast = M$$
Now do your two seconds of thought and write down one concise line proving that $A^\ast A$ is hermitian for any matrix $A$. If instead you need proof for the first statement, ask for that.